# MAX() usage in GROUP BY with non-numeric column

Tags: hiveql

I have a table similar to the following

```
UserId  | ActionType
--------------------
1       | Create
2       | Read
1       | Edit
2       | Create
3       | Read
```

I want to find the "highest" action that a user has done, with the following hierarchy `Create > Edit > Read`. Running the desired query should return

```
UserId | ActionType
-------------------
1      | Create
2      | Create
3      | Read
```

Is there a way to leverage `MAX()` in HIVE to do this? My structure looks like the following very basic query but I'm unsure how to compute the above ActionType column.

`SELECT UserId, ??? FROM UserActions GROUP BY UserId;`

I think possible solutions are `CASE` statements in the `GROUP BY` or converting the values into numeric values, such as `(Read => 0, Edit => 1, Create => 2)` and then doing a `GROUP BY`, but I am hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you want to group by UserId, because you want the "max" per user, so if this was regular SQL (I don't know HiveQL, unfortunately) you'd put the MAX(CASE ...) expression in the SELECT clause, and leave the GROUP BY clause as it is.

Comment: Ooh interesting, I think that will serve my purpose!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if **hiveql** supports sub queries, but this is the idea if it was on SQL :

```
SELECT
  a.UserId,
  a.ActionType
From
  a.UserActions
WHERE
  a.ActionType = (
    SELECT
      b.ActionType
    From
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(COUNT(*)),
          c.ActionType
        FROM
          UserActions as c
        WHERE
          c.UserId = a.UserId
        GROUP BY
          c.ActionType
      ) as b
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Below would be query in hive.

```
select
t1.userId, t1.actionType, 
min(case when t1.actionType='Create' then 1 else 100
when t1.actionType='Edit' then 2 else 100
when t1.actionType='Read' then 3 else 100 end) as GroupBy
from mytable t1 group by t1.userId, t1.actionType
```